# Why does method "isspace" accept non-space characters in conditional statement?

Tags: python, python-3.5

In the following program, I want the program to exit if the input string contains any chars that are not digits, letters, or spaces. But when using the method "isspace" in my 2nd conditional elif statement, it accepts non-space characters. For example, technically if I insert any of the following characters into my input string, the program should exit with exit(-1), but it does not: ":", ";", ".", or "*"
Using a debugger, I see that it actually enters the 2nd conditional elif statement, which should not be happening. I've tested & verified in the python3 terminal that the statement

```
";".isspace()
```

does evaluate to "False", yet in my code below it apparently does not.
Why is this happening?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

lets = 0
nums = 0
inp = input("enter input")
for i in range(len(inp)):
    if inp[i].isdigit():
        nums += 1
    elif inp[i].isalpha():
        lets += 1
    elif inp[i].isspace:
        pass
    else:
        print("invalid entry, try again")
        exit(-1)
print("LETTERS {:10d}\nDIGITS {:10d}".format(lets, nums))
```

Comment: `inp[i].isspace` is a function. All functions are truthy. You forgot to call the function - change to `inp[i].isspace()`, like in other tests you did.

Comment: The code you posted contains a typo. The line should be: `elif inp[i].isspace():`

Comment: got it. dumb error